# Streaming problem in WCF

Tags: wcf

I am using WCF's `basicHttpBinding` streaming as follows:

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="test"
           contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" />

   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="test" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

The problem occurs when I am creating a client from my WCF services (adding a reference). On the client side it is showing `transferMode="Streamed"`. This is working fine if I am using the `netTcpBinding`.

Comment: What problem? Do you get an error, a hunch or something completely different?

Comment: no error,i got the answer,check the answer 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP transports, the transfer mode does not propagate across a connection, or to servers and other intermediaries. Setting the transfer mode is not reflected in the description of the service interface. After generating a client class for a service, you must edit the configuration file for services intended to be used with streamed transfers to set the mode. For TCP and named pipe transports, the transfer mode is propagated as a policy assertion.